# show 3 items per row in vuejs

Tags: html, css, typescript, vue.js

I have a usecase in vue.js where i have multiple items which are basically cards,now i want to show them in rows where each row has 3 cards,Below is the way i tried(I have removed the  to shorten the code).

```
<template>
  <div class="container" @scroll="handleScroll">
    <div class="card-container">
      <!-- Loop through the products data and display cards horizontally -->
      <AddCourseCard />

      <CoursesCard
        v-for="(item, index) in dummyData"
        :key="index"
        :title="item.title"
        :text="item.text"
        :imageSrc="item.imageSrc"
        class="card"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<style scoped>
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Added to enable scrolling */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center; /* Center the cards horizontally */
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 1216px; /* Set a max-width for the container */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center the container horizontally */
}

.card {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 10px);
  max-width: calc(33.33% - 10px);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Include padding and border in card width */
}
</style>
```

here I have to render `AddCourseCard` only when user is admin,it will render as first element,if user is not admin,the original list will start rendering as usual.

Now the problem is like if i have 7 elements here,the 7th will go in 3rd row and ideally should be at first position of 3rd row but it gets in the middle of the third row which looks very wierd.

does anyone know a fix for this or any other better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tr to remove `justify-content: center;` from `.card-container` class:

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const dummyData = ref([{id: 1, title: 'aaa'}, {id: 2, title: 'bbb'}, {id: 3, title: 'ccc'}, {id: 4, title: 'ddd'}, {id: 5, title: 'eee'}, {id: 6, title: 'fff'}, {id: 7, title: 'ggg'}]);
    return { dummyData }
  }
})
app.component('child', {
  template: `
  <div>
    {{ data.title }}
  </div>
  `,
  props: ['data']
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 1216px;
}

.card {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 10px);
  max-width: calc(33.33% - 10px);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card-container">
      <!--<AddCourseCard />-->
      <child
        v-for="(item, index) in dummyData"
        :key="index"
        :data="item"
        class="card"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```